# What does "Headless running out of the box" mean for test framework?

Tags: testing, frameworks, translate

on this website

http://www.techtalkdc.com/which-javascript-test-library-should-you-use-qunit-vs-jasmine-vs-mocha/

there is a comparison of different Testing Frameworks. In the pros of Jasmine and Mocha it says: "Headless running out of the box"

Can anyone explain what this means? I am not sure, as English is not my first language.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Headless" in terms of test automation framework means that it runs the test without having browser user interface.

In terms of automated testing it can bring some advantages like increased execution speed and stability, since again the user interface is not there and there is no time spent rendering it.